# Whether the return value of HMAC is free-able or not

Tags: c++, hmac

I used below message authentication code in my C++ project:

```
unsigned char *digest = HMAC(EVP_sha1(), privateKey.c_str(), strlen(privateKey.c_str()), (unsigned char*)publickey, strlen(publickey), NULL, &mdLength);
```

I didn't find whether the return value (digest) is free-able or not in HMAC API definition. Would please tell me, can I free it after use?

Comment: If you provide NULL for the target (which you did via the second-to-last argument), [the result is placed in a static array](https://wiki.openssl.org/index.php/Manual:Hmac(3)) that will overwrite with successive calls. If this code is threaded or you need to retain multiple results, definitely provide a local buffer of size `EVP_MAX_MD_SIZE` rather than using the static storage. you probably should anyway, as it can make for difficult bugs down the road .

Comment: @WhozCraig Thank you!